# 403 forbidden error in jmeter but api works fine in postman

Tags: jmeter, postman

I have an API that is running in GET method. It works fine in postman with `200` status code. But when I try to run the API in jmeter it throws `403` forbidden error. I have configured the debug sampler and tried to re-run the test. The debug sampler passed with `200` but http request still fails.

1. I have tried to correlate but even that fails.
2. I removed the port number from the HTTP request, it still fails.
3. I have added the authorization manager and enter the username and password still fails.
4. HTTP cookie manager and cache manager added in the script.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) description

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

Most probably you have inconsistencies between requests originated from Postman and from JMeter.

There are 2 possible causes:

1. You failed to configure JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler properly. Given your request works fine in Postman you can try to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

   - Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is going for [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/)

     - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
     - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"
   - Prepare Postman for recording.

     - On Settings page set proxy host to `127.0.0.1` and port to `8888`

       [image]
   - Execute the request in Postman

     - JMeter will capture the request and store it under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)
2. Postman uses specific [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header which cannot be recorded and replayed. Look into `Authorization` tab for the request and check which one is used, once you figure out - implement the same in JMeter:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Status Code 403 means you are not authorized to access it, so Ensure you are using the right Authorization for your GET call.

Answer (score 0):

Add cookie manager in jmeter http sampler.